# Scroll to id PHP function

Tags: php

I have a form that on submit refreshes the page and shows the errors.I just need it to scroll back to the form.This is the form tag:

```
<form id='contactus' action='<?php echo $formproc->GetSelfScript(); ?>' method='post' accept-charset='UTF-8'>
```

This is the function:

```
function GetSelfScript()
{
    return htmlentities($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);
}
```

How do I add the #contact to the function?

Thanks!

Comment: does action="#contactus" not work? why use php?

Comment: Agreed.  In the `GetSelfScript()` method append `#contactus` to the returned value or simply do it directly in the `action` attribute.

Comment: Can you be more specific? I'm really new to PHP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need php here. Append the id of the element you want to jump to as an anchor to the action field.

e.g.

```
<form id="contactUs" action="target.php#contactUs" />
```

in your case (whatever is appropiate)

```
<form id='contactus' action='<?php echo $formproc->GetSelfScript(); ?>#contactus' method='post' accept-charset='UTF-8'>
```

or

```
function GetSelfScript($anchor = null)
{
    $anchor = $anchor === null ? '' : '#' . $anchor;
    return htmlentities($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']) . '#' . $anchor;
}
```

and

```
<form id='contactus' action='<?php echo $formproc->GetSelfScript("contactus"); ?>#contactus' method='post' accept-charset='UTF-8'>
```

Comment: A little edit to your answer will do: <form id='contactus' action='<?php echo $formproc->GetSelfScript(); ?>contact' method='post' accept-charset='UTF-8'> plus the modified function you added worked. Thanks! PS otherwise i get sent to page.php##contact